# Why some UWP projects has project.json some doesnt has?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I can see that some UWP projects has project.json file and all the NuGet packages entries are included in the project.json. But some UWP projects doesnt has project.json. NuGet packages entries are included in .csproj file itself. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In earlier stages of developing .NET Core tooling **project.json** (developed by ASP.NET Core team) was seen as a better way to manage NuGet packages, but later decision was made to move back to **.csproj** for various reasons. So now UWP is storing references to packages in **.csproj** since it's using .NET Core as well. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) and [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/project-json-replaced-by-csproj).

**EDIT:**

If I understand correctly, managing packages in **.csproj** requires Visual Studio 2017, and VS 2015 only understands **project.json**. That is why, by default, if you create UWP project in VS 2017 it will add **project.json** to be backwards compatible with VS 2015 (unless you target Creators Update which isn't supported by 2015 anyway).

However, even if you create a project without **project.json** in VS 2017 and lower its TargetPlatformVersion, it will still work, but only in VS 2017. So to decide to use **project.json** or not, you should simply decide whether you want to support VS 2015 or not.

[This discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/654) might clear it more.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm developing templates for UWP. How can I decide to use project.json or not? It seems its depend on the TargetPlatformVersion of the project. If yes, till what version I need to use project.json and from which version I need to use PackageReferences in .csproj? Any link will be useful. Thanks in advance.