# Why am I getting this error "...cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime" in UWP?

Tags: c#, nuget, windows-10-universal

I'm getting two build errors in a pull request branch...

1. Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
2. Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'

I am working with a Universal Windows Platform project which has the following NuGet packages in its references *sometimes*:

- Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
- Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face
- WindowsAzue.Storage

I was reviewing a pull request in a different directory and these did not appear in the references. They do however appear in the NuGet Package Manager. I can install them and uninstall them, but they do not appear in the References for the project in VS 2017.

Build Clean with deleting bin and obj directories and then rebuild does not resolve this build error.

Reinstalling the NuGet packages does not resolve it either.

A stranger mystery to me is where the NuGet Package Configuration for Windows Universal is kept? My hope was that I could manage them with packages.config, and then expect to see them in the packages directory under my project directory. Neither of these things exist in the solution. Have these things changed with NuGet 3? I think understanding this is key.

My project can successfully be built, packaged, and deployed from code in the master branch. It is just this pull request that seems to fail.

The only difference between the branches that appeared to be significant was with the project.json and project.lock.json, which I copied over to no avail.

**EDIT**
After reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917060/117995, I decided to remove the project.json file which I had just copied.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: No. This still occurs in the PR branch.

Comment: I created a blank UWP project(target platform version 17134) and install these packages, then, I could build the project successfully.